# React Native: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNViewShot.CacheDir')

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to use [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot) in my app. However I keep getting error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNViewShot.CacheDir')

I've tried to clean + rebuild the project but doesn't seem to have any effects at all. I've also close and restart the packager but the error still remains. I've checked the files in android folder and all the codes that is needed is there (According to the Manual Installation section). Anybody have any idea how to fix this issue? I need to use it for taking a screenshots of part of the screen.

React Native version: 0.46.1

Platform: Android

Test Device: Emulator (Nexus_5_API_24)

UPDATE:

I managed to make the app run properly after doing several things.

I noticed in the packager there's a warning about kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped. According to https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html this is because the system limit was hit. So what I did was:

1. Set the fsevents_latency parameter in my .watchmanconfig file to
   0.02.
2. Shutdown watchman.
3. Restart my computer (this was because my computer was lagging, not sure if it have any effect)
4. Run react-native start to start the packager again.
5. Start the emulator.
6. Run react-native run-android.

I'm not really sure what actually caused the issue, but my best guess is; due to the system having hit the limit, it cannot fully compile the module. This caused the module to not load properly which caused the error. Thus increasing the limit allows it to process everything completely.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means you've failed to install the library properly, since it is not being exported by `NativeModules`. So I'd look over the manual installation guide again, or try to re-do automatic linking with `react-native link`.

If that fails, it may be a cache issue with the React Native packager. So stop the packager, and reset cache with `npm start -- --reset-cache` from the app project directory.

Comment: I did try restarting the packager, but it didn't changed anything. I actually just managed to get it to run. Not really sure what actually fixed it; but I think it might have something to do with kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped warning that I keep getting in the packager.